# Weird issue found trying to match a expression with a input that has paranthesis without evaluating(Sympy)

Tags: python, numpy, latex, expression, sympy

I have gone into detail in this issue thread https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23709

but the gist is that I am trying to get the coefficients of an equation in the form:

```
parsed_input = 7*x + 4*(10*x + 6) >= 8*x + 15
```

I am using the pattern:

```
x = Wild("x",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Symbol)])
a = Wild("a",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])
p = Wild("p",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])
q = Wild("q",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])
b = Wild("b",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])
c = Wild("c",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])
r = Wild("r",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])
s = Wild("s",  properties=[lambda x: isinstance(x, Integer)])

expected_output = Ge(Mul(a, (p*x + q)) +b*x + c,  r*x + s)
```

But when I do:

```
matching = parsed_input.match(expected_output)
```

I am mostly getting a=1 , p=40, q=24 and some other times I get a=4,p=10, q=6

How can I get  a=4,p=10, q=6 everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a custom parser can help:

```
def parse(eq,x=None):
    from sympy import Add, ordered
    from sympy.utilities.iterables import sift
    if x is None:
        from sympy.abc import x
    bcxd, axe = sift(Add.make_args(eq), lambda _: _.has(Add), binary=True)
    if len(bcxd) == 2:
        axe, bcxd = [[i] for i in bcxd]
        if axe[0].is_Mul:
            axe, bcxd = bcxd, axe
    assert len(bcxd) < 2
    assert len(axe) < 3
    e, ax = Add(*axe).as_coeff_Add()
    if not ax:
        a = 0
    else:
        a,X = ax.as_coeff_Mul()
        assert X == x
    if not bcxd:
        b=c=d=0    
    else:
        bcxd = bcxd.pop()
        if bcxd.is_Add:
            b = 1
            cxd = bcxd
        else:
            b,cxd = ordered(bcxd.args)
        if cxd.is_Mul:
            d = 0
            cx = cxd
        else:
            d,cx = ordered(cxd.args)
        c,X = cx.as_independent(x, as_Add=False)
        if X == 1:
            c,d=0,c
        else:
            assert X == x
    return dict(zip('abcde',(a,b,c,d,e)))

from sympy import S
from sympy.abc import x
assert parse(S(3)) == {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 3}
assert parse(x) == {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0}
assert parse(3*x) == {'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0}
assert parse(3*x+4) == {'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 4}
assert parse(3*x+4+Mul(1,x+7,evaluate=False)) == {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 7, 'e': 4}
assert parse(3*x+4+Mul(1,2*x+7,evaluate=False)) == {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 7, 'e': 4}
assert parse(3*x+4+Mul(6,2*x+7,evaluate=False)) == {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'd': 7, 'e': 4}
with evaluate(False):
    eq = 2+3*x+4*(5*x+6)

assert parse(eq) == dict(zip('abcde', (3,4,5,6,2)))
```

Comment: I tried moving to your code as it was more structured but it gives assertion errors too many times, sympy's as_coeff_Mul, as_coeff_Add and such functions used are not working as intended

Comment: d, cx = A.as_coeff_Add()

Specifically this line, d is becoming 0 and cx is remaining as 10*x+6 same as A

Comment: Very sorry if this is a basic question, but i have defined all the other a,bc,d,e,x as constants and symbols, do I need to do the same for X as well?

Comment: code is updated; you should be able to verify the output by typing in the lines that are given in parse's docstring. Try again and if something fails give the expression that failed, e.g. `parse(2+3*x) -> error`

Comment: Thanks for the help but very oddly, as_coeff_Add fails to work expected for me, also your code for getting the constant e is 100% correct but weirdly for me, sympy does not turn the brackets into args and just gives me args as (2, 7x + 4(8x+10))

I implemented some of my own code for handling this case but just wanted to put it here if it can help anyone else

Comment: It was not clear that your expression was totally unevaluated. That really makes hand parsing a lot harder since methods like `Expr.as_coeff_Mul()` can no longer assume that the coefficient will be first. I modified the code and gave tests as an example of what you  might try. I doubt that using Wild will be of help with such expressions.

Comment: There is an updated code and followup [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23709). Parsing the unevaluated expression is a bit of a headache.